# VB.Net Looping over text boxes to check if they contain only numbers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im working on a simple university project, which has to registers a new member. Right now im busy with form validation.

Some of my textboxes can only contain text and not letters, the code I use to check if the textboxes which must only accept text is as follows:

```
'check textboxes contains only characters'
        'initial'
        If Not System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(vinital, "^[a-z]*$", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success Then
            MsgBox("Initial can only contain text .")
        End If
```

**My question**

Instead of doing one if statment at a time for every textbox, how can I loop over them using similar code as above to validate for text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to put all your controls in a `Panel` and then iterate through it like this (untested, but you get the idea):

```
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In Panel1.Controls 'Me.Controls should also work, I think.
    If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Then
        Dim txt As TextBox = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
        'check content of txt here
    End If
Next
```